# Dismiss() not working for Customize AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I am developing a android App which is totally based on request and response from servlet.I have populate some data in customize Alert-dialog Where i using two  thing one is cross button that will delete item from list in alert-dialog and update view of alert dialog , second thing is close button that will suppose to dismiss this alert-dialog. I am showing full coding of my alert-dialog. I calling alert dialog on button click by all these method.

```
 intiliazeOrderListDialog();
 showOrderListDialog();
```

My decleration is as follow

```
public AlertDialog detailsDialog, orderDialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
```

Now i am going to post my intiliazeOrderListDialog() block.

```
    public void intiliazeOrderListDialog() {  

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    orderDialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_order_list,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.order_list_root));
    orderList = (ListView) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.order_list);

    ibOrderDelete = (ImageButton)orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.deleteOrder);
    tvPrice = (TextView) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.order_list_total);
    tvTaxes = (TextView) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.order_list_taxes);
    tvTotal = (TextView) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.order_list_grand_total);
    Button bclose = (Button) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.close);
    Button bPlaceOrder = (Button) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_order_placeorder);
    bclose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {                     
            orderDialog.dismiss();    

            System.out.println(" click on closowse");

        }      
    });

    bPlaceOrder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Place order click");

            palceMyOrdertoServer();
            new SendOrderFromTable().execute();
            System.out.println("place order to server is called");
            String msg = "Your Order is Successfully placed to Kitcken";
            Message msgObject = new Message();
            msgObject.what = 1;
            msgObject.obj = msg;
            addMenuItemHandler.sendMessage(msgObject);


            orderDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }); 
}
```

and at last i am going to post showOrderListDialog(); block

```
  public void showOrderListDialog() {  
    builder.setView(orderDialogLayout);
    orderDialog = builder.create();
    orderDialog.show();
}
```

I know i have posted too many codes but its conveniences for those who want to help me . I have a very simple problem why my

```
            orderDialog.dismiss();
```

is not working for me.? Thanks in advance to all .

Comment: Its not dismissing the dialog because in your method its not able to get the exact instance of `orderDialog`.

Comment: Thanks... for response. but may you explain little more ?your little help means a lot for me.

Comment: Why you have created this method `showOrderListDialog()`? where are you using it?  Though in your `intiliazeOrderListDialog()` method you are already inflating the layout then what is the need of passing layout again in `showOrderListDialog()` ?

Comment: @GrIsHu...Your suggestion doesn't work for me I am still getting same issue

Comment: I didn't give any suggestions yet.

Comment: So what you think what is issue?

Comment: First tell me Why you have created this method `showOrderListDialog()`? where are you using it? Though in your `intiliazeOrderListDialog()` method you are already inflating the layout then what is the need of passing layout again in `showOrderListDialog()` ?

Comment: intiliazeOrderListDialog();
 createOrderListDialog();
 showOrderListDialog(); I am calling all these three method sequentally to show my customize alert-dialog.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40032/discussion-between-blue-green-and-grishu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solve my own issue . "Self help is best help ;;".

It was issue of calling method in setOnClickListener.

I just call it,

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="clickHandler"

    if (v.getId() == R.id.myOrder) {
        System.out.println("Click my Order");
        System.out.println("OrderListAdapter.totalCount  ="
                + OrderListAdapter.totalCount);
        // select COUNT(*) from CDs;

        int jcount = 0;
        jcount = countjournals();
        System.out.println("jcount = " + jcount);

        // Count implementation at my Order
        if (jcount < 1) {
            alertShow();
        } else {
            intiliazeOrderListDialog();
            showOrderListDialog();
        }

        // startActivity(new Intent(RestaurantHome.this,
        // MyOrderList.class));

    }
```